# How do you increase icon weight in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

How can you increase/decrease the weight of an icon (vector) in Sketch?

For increase: 
- I added an outside border around the icon, then did Layers -> Convert Outlines.

I got this:
[image: Icon after Converting to Outlines]

Any tips on increasing and/or decreasing the weight of an icon in Sketch and properly exporting it so it doesn't look super jank in Illustrator or on the Web would be SUPER appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I always set the same color with border.

Three steps I need to do:

1st, Import/Create your icon.
[image]

2nd, Add a border style.
[image]

3rd, Pick the same color.
[image]

Finished! 
[image]